# Have camel build the endpoint uri with a Map

Tags: java, apache-camel

Is there a way to have camel create the uri of an endpoint using a `Map<String, String>`, that contains the request parameters?

I regularly have the case, that I get different parameters via the configuration and have to build the uri programatically at runtime (after that its static).
At the moment I always have to build the uri myself, which works find, but I wonder if there is a cleaner way.

For example, this is how I build the uri for a smtp enpoint using some configuration (probably not the simplest code, but it works fine):

```java
private String buildSmtpUri() {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  if (configuration.isEnableSslSecurity()) {
    sb.append("smtps://");
  } else {
    sb.append("smtp://");
  }
  Assert.hasText(configuration.getSmtpUrl(), "No smtp url was given");
  sb.append(configuration.getSmtpUrl());
  if (configuration.getPort() != null) {
    sb.append(":");
    sb.append(configuration.getPort());
  }
  Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
  if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(configuration.getUsername())) {
    parameters.put("username", configuration.getUsername());
  }
  if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(configuration.getPassword())) {
    parameters.put("password", configuration.getPassword());
  }
  if (configuration.isBodyIsHtml()) {
    parameters.put("contentType", "text/html");
  }

  AtomicBoolean first = new AtomicBoolean(true);
  parameters.forEach((key, value) -> {
    if (first.get()) {
      first.set(false);
      sb.append("?");
    } else {
      sb.append("&");
    }
    sb.append(key)
        .append("=")
        .append(value);
  });

  return sb.toString();
}
```

If this can't be simplified using some camel interface, maybe it might be a cool feature in the future?

Greets
Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Component#createEndpoint`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-api/3.0.0/org/apache/camel/Component.html#createEndpoint-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-) method to build [`Endpoint`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-api/3.0.0/org/apache/camel/Endpoint.html) instance dynamically.

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception{
        from(dynamicEndpoint("seda", "mySeda", Collections.singletonMap("size", "123")))
                .to("log:Hello from SEDA");
    }

    private Endpoint dynamicEndpoint(String component, String name, Map<String, Object> params) throws Exception {
        return getContext().getComponent(component).createEndpoint(name, params);
    }
}
```

In Camel 2.x, there is also solution, alhough not so elegant

```
private Endpoint dynamicEndpoint(String component, String name, Map<String, Object> params) throws Exception {
    String uri = String.format("%s://%s?%s", component, name, org.apache.camel.util.URISupport.createQueryString(params));
    return getContext().getEndpoint(uri);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution though I couldn't test it, because we still use Camel 2, where there is only "createEndpoint" with the name and no params. But I will use this method as soon as we migrate. Thanks

Comment: @Chris I have added a code for Camel 2. It is a bit uglier than Camel 3 approach, but still much shorter than your original approach.

Comment: For everyone wondering with the Camel 2.x code, camel is fine with having a trailing '?' without parameters, so there is no need to check for an empty parameter map. @Bedla thanks for the code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i think there is simpler way. You can use [simple language](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/simple-language.html) to make uri. Also you can combine it with your own Processes in `process(Process process)` after `simple` expression. For example, you can set endpoint using `simple`, then add `process()` endpoint, where you can change endpoint or make new `String uri` which you can pass to next endpoint using `setHeader()` in processor.